# Picture field in database

Tags: database

I need to create a db table in `postgresql` or `mysql`, and one of this table is a jpeg/png file. What do you recommend type of the given field?

Comment: I’d store the image data in AWS / Azure Blob storage and only keep the URI in the database. Bonus points if you use Content-Addressable Storage scheme and treat binary blobs as immutable.

Comment: @Dai , Oh no, I need to store my content file in my db.

Comment: Why do you need to store large binaries **directly inside** your database? Generally speaking it's a bad idea. IO perf for embedded blobs inside most RDBMS is generally terrible.